# NumberPicker with array from database

Tags: java, android, firebase, numberpicker

I wanted to help me develop a numberpicker with a list that I get from firebase, this code now gives me an error and if I delete "setMaxValue and MinValue" it only brings me a single value.

```
    CBSList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(post.getIDPost()).child("CBS");

    reference.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            CBSList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                CBSList.add(snapshot.getKey());

                String array[] = new String[CBSList.size()];
                for(int j =0;j<CBSList.size();j++){
                    array[j] = CBSList.get(j);
                }

                numberPicker.setMaxValue(CBSList.size() - 1);
                numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
                numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(array);
                numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );
```

error if I leave the two lines of min and max

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ibra.kl, PID: 13463
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>           at android.widget.NumberPicker.ensureCachedScrollSelectorValue(NumberPicker.java:1900)
>           at android.widget.NumberPicker.initializeSelectorWheelIndices(NumberPicker.java:1715)
>           at android.widget.NumberPicker.setMaxValue(NumberPicker.java:1471)
>           at com.example.ibra.kl.ProductoPostActivity$2.onDataChange(ProdActivity.java:143)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Comment: @azurefrog corrected.

Comment: As I can understand, you have more than one value in your database?

Comment: @Amine Yes......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `setMaxValue` and `setMinValue` before `CBSList` is completely filled.

Change your code like this

```
reference.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        CBSList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            CBSList.add(snapshot.getKey());
        }

        String array[] = new String[CBSList.size()];

        for(int j =0;j<CBSList.size();j++){
            array[j] = CBSList.get(j);
        }

        if (CBSList.size() > 1) {
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(CBSList.size() - 1);
            numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
            numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(array);
            numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
} );
```